# Power Analysis: Comparing GLM to binomial proportion test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, statistical-power, proportion

I am trying to run a power analysis using simulated data to compare the power of a glm versus a binomial proportion test to detect differences in proportions. For example, suppose you have some proportion that decreases by some amount over X number of time steps.
.4,.39,.38,.37 . . . . .01 and simulate data over those time steps based on the decrease. Does a glm approach (differences in slope) “outperform” an approach whereby you simply look at proportional differences. I ran simulations and basically summed up the number of times p<.05 divided by the number of trials.  I was expecting that a glm approach would have more power because it would be utilizing all the data across multiple time steps, whereas a binomial proportion test is only comparing two populations ( the beginning and the end points).

However the results indicated that a binomial proportion test had more power relative to a glm at fewer time steps and that, depending on the simulated decrease in proportions, the relationship between glm power and binomial proportion test power changed. Interestingly, at greater decreases in the proportion, a binomial proportion test seems have greater power compared to a glm, which to me is counterintuitive since the slope of the glm should be greater.

I am attaching the code below my questions in case anyone is interested.

My questions are:

(1) Am I interpreting the results and p-values correctly?
(2) If I am interested in trends, does glm results really have lower power and, if so, is there a way to combine the two tests?

I realize that a glm or other approach to analyze trends is the way to go,

Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.

```
##### Attempt at using glm model ######
    ltProb <- 0.4                       ## longterm average of nest survival probability
    change <- c(.01,.03,.05)
    yrs <- seq(1,20, by=1)                                                    ## Years of inquiry, probability of detecting a yearly change nest survival 
    samplesize <- 50                                               ## Reasonable sample size range
    reps <- 1000                                                                       ## of simulations per 
    SurvProb <- ltProb                                                           ## initiating survival probablity for later use, nuisance
    power <- matrix(nrow=length(change)*length(yrs)*length(samplesize), ncol=5) ## creating a matrix to hold data

    scenario <- 0                                                                      ## initializing scenarios which will be a placeholder later on
    for (a in 1:length(change)){                                                         ## loop through yearly pop change scenarios
      for (c in 1:length(samplesize)){                                                                ## loop through sample size scenarios
        for (b in 1:length(yrs)){                                                                              ## loop through years sceanarios
          scenario=scenario+1
          power[scenario,1] <- change[a]                                                                                                                                                                                          ## filling matrix with pop change used
          power[scenario,2]<-ltProb*((1-change[a])**yrs[b])
          power[scenario,3] <- yrs[b]                                                                                                                                                                                  ## filling matrix with number of years used
          power[scenario,4] <- samplesize[c]                                                                                                                                                                                   ## filling matrix with sample size used
        }
      }
    }
    colnames(power) <- c("PopChange", "Proportion2","yrs", "Sample_Size", "Power")
    power=as.data.frame(power)
    power$Sample_Size=as.numeric(power$Sample_Size)

    scenario=levels(as.factor(power$PopChange)) ## To subset power
        ps = levels(as.factor(power$Sample_Size))
    results <- matrix(nrow=0, ncol=5) ## final matrix
    results=as.data.frame(results)
    reps=1000 ## set number of reps

    for (k in 1:length(scenario)){
      for (m in 1:length(ps)){
        sub=power[(power$PopChange==scenario[k]) & power$Sample_Size==ps[m],] ## Subset by scenario and sample size
        probs = matrix(nrow=1000,ncol=16) ## this is matrix for probabilities.
        dat=matrix(nrow=0,ncol=3,NA)
        dat=as.data.frame(dat)
        for (l in 1:reps){ ##This should be for the replicates
          dat=matrix(nrow=0,ncol=3,NA)
          dat=as.data.frame(dat)
          print(l)
          for (j in 1:nrow(sub)){
            tmp=rbinom(n=sub$Sample_Size[j],size=1,prob=sub[j,2])
                tmp.dat=cbind(tmp,rep(sub$yrs[j],sub$Sample_Size[j]),rep(sub$Proportion2[j],sub$Sample_Size[j]))
                dat=rbind(dat,tmp.dat)
                if (sub$yrs[j]>4){
              x=(glm(dat[,1]~dat[,2],family=binomial))
              probs[l,j-4]=ifelse(summary(x)$coefficients[2,4]<.05,1,0)
                }
              }
            }
            sub$Power[5:20]=apply(probs,2,sum)/nrow(probs)
        results=rbind(results,sub)
      }
    }

    tmp=results[!is.na(results$Power),] ### remove NAs
        tmp$SampleSize_Decline=paste(tmp$Sample_Size,tmp$PopChange,sep=":")
    tmp$SampleSize_Decline=as.factor(tmp$SampleSize_Decline)

    ### Now do the same using prop.test #####
    tmp$PropPower = NA
        for (i in 1:nrow(tmp)){
          print(i)
          x=0
          for (j in 1:1000){
            a = rbinom(tmp$Sample_Size[i],1,prob = (tmp$Proportion2[i]))
            b=binom.test(sum(a),length(a),p=.4,conf.level=.95,alternative="less")
            if (b$p.value < .05) {x=x+1}
          }
          tmp$PropPower[i] = x/1000
    }

    ##### graph results
    d=unique(tmp$PopChange)
        for (i in 1:length(d)){
          par(mfcol = c(1,2))
          sub = tmp[tmp$PopChange == d[i],]
          plot(sub$yrs,sub$Power,col="red", main = d[i], xlab = "Number of years",ylab="Power")
          points(sub$yrs,sub$PropPower,col="black")
          plot(sub$PropPower,sub$Power,xlab="Binomial Proportion Power", ylab="GLM Power",main=d[i])
      abline(0,1)
      readline("Press <return to continue")
    }


    ##### End Code #####
```

Comment: +1 I have the same question yet slightly different. I was wondering if one needs to simulate a trend anyway, if one assumes a specific difference after e.g. 10 years. Simulation of glm trends takes ages! a quick binomial proportion test could be just as fine, but from your findings it seems they differ strongly. Maybe due to the possible variation along the trendline?? this would not be considered in a proportion test. Did you get any other feedback yet?